# Why we would need public IP in LAN vs NAT

Tags: routing, ip, router, nat, wide-area-network

could somebody explain why I would need some public IP for an equipement inside the LAN while I could NAT it ?

Why a company could be provided a full subnet of public ip and not just one for the router ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, today there really is no reason.

You only need IP addresses on the internet to provide services to the internet, and you can do one of them (like a web server) despite NAT (reverse NAT being a thing).

In the old times, there was a need - protocols and NAT devices both not really being built with proper NAT in mind (i.e. FTP is crap for NAT unless the NAT device supports parsing it, which was not really that common in the beginning, it is now).

So, no - unless you provide services, hide the whole network behind NAT (and if you do provide services, put in a demilitarized zone).

Comment: Thank you, could I stll have a web server in DMZ  with a public IP (or it is a nonsense cause a DMZ should have a private subnet ? )

Comment: Well, you could put a web server behind reverse NAT - as well as email. A DMZ would still make sense so that if someone hacks the website (and thus the server possibly) the damage is contained and not going directly to company servers.

Comment: Your question assumed one public IP address for the router. If you want an additional public address on a web server you can get that.  The alterative is port forwarding through the NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Globally routable prefixes and addressing each host is easier.

NAT is expensive stateful tracking of connections attempting to maintain address mappings. Behind a NAT, only one well-known port mapping per public IP address. Further, the real client address is unknown on the LAN, and tends to require application level hacks to pass through. And sometimes peer to peer or FTP is not functional and needs special help traversing NAT. Yes, it can work. You have internalized the cost because you do not know anything better, in this era of IPv4 exhaustion.

Try implementing IPv6. Might be refreshing to put a web server load balancer on a vanity address  such as   `2001:db8:2381:2935::443`  and be able to identify hosts even as they go through the router.

Comment: NAT is expensive stateful tracking of connections attempting to maintain address mappings -> Irrelevant until you run offices with hundreds or thousands of computers.

Comment: Further, the real client address is unknown on the LAN, and tends to require application level hacks to pass through. -> Which is perfect for 99.99999999% of all software businesses apply.

Comment: And sometimes peer to peer or FTP is not functional and needs special help traversing NAT -> which is irrelevant in 99.9999999999% of all use cases, or just works (FTP, non moronic NAT)